# Trigger placing a point in qgis to autocomplete a column by adding the next in an alphanumeric sequence in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, qgis, postgresql-triggers

In QGIS, I have a table of points, and a table of areas. When I place a point in an area, I need the following to happen. Grab the ID of the area (called plat_page) the new point is being placed in. Then I want to insert the next value in a sequence into the new entry in a column called "node_id" based on what points already exist in that area. My issue is that the sequence is alpha numeric, where the first 4 characters are the plat_page, and the last three are the sequence. As well, I am unsure how to discern the area I have placed the new point in. The "node_id" looks something like this:

`510C101` where `510C` is the plat_page, and `101` is the number that I need to sequence.

Here is an example, I place a point in an area with plat_page `610C`. I want to get the plat_page, then check what the highest value in the existing sequence is, lets say `100`. Then I want to generate the next value in the sequence `610C101` and insert that into a column called "node_id".

So far I have a way to grab the highest number in the sequence for a given plat_page, but I want to automate this process by having the insertion point decide what that plat page is. As well, I am unsure how to sequence the last number, then attach it to the plat_page value to generate the "node_id". Below is the code for what I have.

```
SELECT MAX(RIGHT ("node_id",3)::numeric) from sewers.structures
    WHERE(
    ST_WITHIN(
        ST_CENTROID((ST_SetSRID(structures.geom, 4326))), 
        ST_SetSRID((SELECT geom FROM sewers."Qrtr_Qrtr_Sections" WHERE "plat_page" = '510D'),4326)) ) and "node_id" != 'PRIVATE'
```

I have also attached this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=638b9e339abd9dd1afd3671a758afeb4) with sample data to help with the understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you want? Get a containing plat_page and the next id for the structures. Omitted ST_SetSRID for simplicity assuming all geometries have the same SRID.

```
select qqs.plat_page,
     (select MAX(RIGHT (s2."node_id",3)::numeric) 
      from structures s2
      where ST_WITHIN(ST_CENTROID(s2.geom), qqs.geom)) + 1 id,
      s.*
from structures s 
join "Qrtr_Qrtr_Sections" qqs on ST_WITHIN(ST_CENTROID(s.geom), qqs.geom)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=77f118ec09a8abe098a5d0dad836a231)

Note I've added an extra row to ensure at least one structure is within "Qrtr_Qrtr_Sections".

Comment: This is closer to what I want, but I am intending for it to be a trigger function. As well, I need the trigger function to auto fill the "node_id" column with an id that is 7 characters long, the first four being the plat_page information, and the last three being the sequenced number.